# no such file directory display while running ruby automation test case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium-webdriver, automation

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
group :test do
    gem 'webdrivers','4.4.2'
    gem "capybara", "~> 3.29.0"
    gem "capybara-screenshot", "~> 1.0"
    gem "rspec-rails", "~> 3.9.0"
    gem "selenium-webdriver", "~> 3.142.6"
    gem 'pry-byebug'
    gem 'pry-rails', '0.3.9'
    gem 'shoulda-callback-matchers'
    gem 'timecop'
    gem "rspec-retry"
end
```

**Sample.rb** test file

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'rspec'
require 'webdrivers'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
driver.navigate.to "http://www.google.com"

element = driver.find_element(name: 'q')
element.click
element.send_keys "Hello webdriver !"
element.submit

driver.quit
```

**running automation test case with below command**

```
rspec sample.rb
```

*display below error on window 10*

```
An error occurred while loading ./sample.rb.
Failure/Error: p = IO.popen(cmd)

Errno::ENOENT:
  No such file or directory - powershell.exe "(Get-ItemProperty 'C:\Program Files\\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe').VersionInfo.ProductVersion"
# ./sample.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
# ------------------
# --- Caused by: ---
# Errno::ENOENT:
#   No such file or directory - pwsh.exe -command "(Get-ItemProperty 'C:\Program Files\\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe').VersionInfo.ProductVersion"
#   ./sample.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
No examples found.


Finished in 0.00003 seconds (files took 1.71 seconds to load)
```

While running this commend on powershell

Get-ItemProperty
'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe').VersionInfo.ProductVersion" it will display the correct version of the chrome browser.

Comment: Isn't problem in PowerShell? powershell.exe/pwsh.exe

Comment: it is not opening the chrome browser. when checking the browser version it display correct browser version